# cant Install [.net core] packages using visual studio code(dotnet cli)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I using the latest asp core 3.1 framework. I am trying to setup my database but there is an issue. I can't seem to install the following packages

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

I get the following errors. will appreciate it if any one can help with 
    a solution.

> error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator ' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
>   error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator ' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1/any'.
>   The tool package could not be restored.
>   Tool 'dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:
>
> - You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
> - A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
> - The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
> - You mistyped the name of the tool.

This happens when I try to install any of the packages.

Comment: I am able to install it without any problem. Can you try running the command with `--verbosity d` and verify what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. this is what i got after  running the command with the verbosity switch

Comment: I think you're missing the output.